# How to read values from the Redis Stream using ServiceStack.Redis Library?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

How to read values from the Redis **Stream** using ServiceStack.Redis Library?
For example, you can read all values from Redis **List** using *RedisClient.GetAllItemsFromList* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack.Redis doesn't support Streams yet, you can [submit a feature request on UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) to request it and be notified when it's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

There is workaround for those who interested:

```
client.ExecLua("return redis.call('XRANGE', '" + stream_name + "', '-', '+')")
```